# Can't recover Nexus 5 from bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, bootloader

Hey I am trying to get my Nexus 5 working again. I really need someone to help me troubleshoot this.

One day I noticed my phone was off after about half an hour from being fully charged. It wouldn't turn on again and my PC would not recognize the device so it wouldn't charge it. I charged it from an outlet but after this it was stuck in the bootloop. (Stuck on those colored circles.)

After looking around on the internet I ended up downloading Minimal ADB and Fastboot. At first 'fastboot devices' command would not work. I eventually figured out that I needed to get the Google USB driver, so I did all that. Now 'fastboot devices' returns something, so that's working.

I can also use command 'fastboot oem unlock' to unlock the device from the bootloader screen.

I have downloaded the latest hammerhead img or whatever, now extracted to C:\hammer. So I have the flash-all.bat file there, as well as flash-all.sh and flash-base.sh. Also, I have the bootloader and radio images renamed to bootloader.img and radio.img. I also have the boot.img, cache.img, recovery.img, system.img, userdata.img filse there.

The flash-all.bat script was not working. I kept getting failure, and the steps where the script reboots the phone didn't work because it would reboot as locked instead of unlocked.

So I decided to try a more manual method. I can't get past the second step, however. The command 'fastboot oem unlock' works, and I can unlock. The command 'fastboot flash bootloader C:\hammer\bootloader.img' returns an error. 'error: cannot load 'C:\hammer\bootloader.img'

That's it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need to know the verbatim output of all the commands you used, regardless of their success or failure. Post screenshots if you can't copy-paste.